# HTML custom form element does not send submit event

Tags: javascript

Created a custom HTML element derived from HTMLFormElement and added listener for "submit" event in constructor. The element is registered properly but the submit handler is never called...

```js
class MyForm extends HTMLFormElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('submit', this.mySubmit);
  }

  mySubmit() {
    console.log('mySubmit was called');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('Custom form element added to page.');
  }
}

customElements.define('my-form', MyForm, {
  extends: 'form'
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-DE">

<head>
  <title>My Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--<script src="myform.js" async="true"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My Form</h1>
  <my-form>
    <p><input type="input" value="Whoa!" /></p>
    <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
  </my-form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You've given the submit handler your own name: `mySubmit()`. Try to use `submit()` instead.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware — It seems like a really bad idea to shadow the native submit method (which *isn't* equivalent to a submit handler)

Comment: @Quentin I agree, that's why it is not an anwser, I only meant to point out what the problem is.

Comment: That isn't the problem though.

Answer (score 3):

As written in the documentation for the custom elements interface, you have to "bind" the custom element functionality to the HTML by using the `is=""` attribute.

There seems to be differences between custom elements:

1) The ones that use their own shadow DOM ( "stand alone element", "autonomous element" ), and hence are forced to extend HTMLElement ( so not HTMLFormElement ), can be written in the `<my-form>` style inside the HTML.

2) For custom elements that do not extend `HTMLElement`, but try to extend other things, like a `HTMLFormElement`, it seems you need to use `<form is="your-defined-name"></form>`, ( "customized builtin element" )

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Customized_built-in_elements

```js
class MyForm extends HTMLFormElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('submit', this.mySubmit);
  }

  mySubmit() {
    console.log('mySubmit was called');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('Custom form element added to page.');
  }
}

customElements.define('my-form', MyForm, {
  extends: 'form'
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-DE">

<head>
  <title>My Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--<script src="myform.js" async="true"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My Form</h1>
  <form is="my-form">
    <p><input type="input" value="Whoa!" /></p>
    <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without `is=""` by inheriting `HTMLElement` by adding your custom `mySubmit` event, consider the following:

```js
'use strict';
class MyForm extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('mySubmit', this.mySubmit);
    debugger;
  }
  get action() {
    return this.getAttribute('action') || window.location.href;
  }
  mySubmit() {
    console.log('mySubmit was called');
    window.location = this.action;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('Custom form element added to page.');
    this.querySelector('[type=mySubmit]').onclick = () => {
      this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('mySubmit')); //,{type: 'submit'});
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('my-form', MyForm); //, {extends: 'form'});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-DE">

<head>
  <title>My Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--<script src="myform.js" async="true"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My Form</h1>
  <my-form action="https://www.google.com">
    <p><input type="input" value="Whoa!" /></p>
    <p><button type="mySubmit">Submit</button></p>
  </my-form>
  <hr>
  <h1>My Form 2</h1>
  <my-form>
    <p><input type="input" value="Whoa2!" /></p>
    <p><button type="mySubmit">Submit</button></p>
  </my-form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Will this actually submit the form when the OP adds the correct action and method to the tag? I have a hunch that by not inheriting the base form functionality, you have to reimplement it again yourself. Compare my solution, where the frame clearly reloads ( trying to submit ), with yours, where the console.log messages stay there and hence, I *think* that you lost all form functionality due to not extending HTMLFormElement anymore. Correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: @Shilly so true, re implementation could be a fuss and inheriting `form` would be more viable. You rock

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help! There was only a tiny piece of code missing to make it happen... 'action="#"' in the  element. Best regards, Oliver

Now the code looks like this and works as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-DE">
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script async="true">
class MyForm extends HTMLFormElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('Custom form element created.');
        this.addEventListener('submit', this.mySubmit);
    }

    mySubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('mySubmit was called');
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('Custom form element added to page.');
    }
}
customElements.define('my-form', MyForm, { extends: 'form' });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Form</h1>
<form is="my-form" action="#">
    <p><input type="input" value="Whoa!"></input></p>
    <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```